# Django - Foreign key filter in forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I have a `Transaction` model and a `Pallet` model,

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=transaction_type_CHOICES)
    palletnumber = models.ForeignKey(Pallet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

class Pallet(models.Model):
    nama_pallet = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    pallet_weight = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)`
```

the thing that I do

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        transaction_type = self.initial.get('transaction_type') or self.instance.transaction_type

        if transaction_type == 'in':
            self.fields['palletnumber'].queryset = Pallet.objects.filter(status=False)
        elif jenis_transaksi == 'keluar':
            self.fields['palletnumber'].queryset = Pallet.objects.filter(status=True)
```

I want to filter the pallet in the transaction form
if the `type = in`: `(status = false)`
if the `type = out`: `(status = true)`

Comment: So is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems good.
I hope you did not expect it to change the pallet choices once the form has been rendered. You'll need to write some JS for that